# PHP upgrade 7.2 to 8 is not recognized by Wordpress

Tags: php, vps, lamp

I have a VPS with LAMP stack and I tried to upgrade to PHP 8. When I run `php -v` the version is 8.1, but WordPress tells me it is 7.2.

So I created a php file

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

which tells me the following:

```
PHP Version 7.2.34-28+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

- I have disabled 7.2

  - `a2dismod php7.2`
- enabled 8.1

  - `a2enmod php8.1`
- restarted apache
- `sudo service apache2 restart`

In the folder `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` I can still see `php7.2-fpm.conf`.

How can I switch to PHP8?

Comment: Check your webbserver config. The PHP-CLI is infact 8.0, but your webserver most likely routes the requests to another PHP-FPM version.